# Spring boot It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I've added the following in my repository

```
@Repository
public interface ReceiptRepository extends JpaRepository<Receipt, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Receipt>{
    public Page<Receipt> findForCriteria(Predicate predicate, Pageable p);
}
```

**QueryDslPredicateExecutor** I'm importing

```
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;
```

and for the **predicate** I'm importing (which I'm not sure if it's the correct one or not)

```
import org.springframework.cglib.core.Predicate;
```

but at my package name I get an error message saying

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class 
 files
- The type com.querydsl.core.types.OrderSpecifier cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

my assumption is that there 2 different jar files having the same package names. Is that correct? If yes then how can I remove one ?

here is my pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.60</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.resthub</groupId>
        <artifactId>springmvc-router</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Import `com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate` instead of the cglib version.

Comment: Also looks like queryDSL support in Spring Data is deprecated, but they have an alternative. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/core.querydsl.html

Answer (score 0):

```
I have added the below dependency and the error got resolved.

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```